# Lighting a Particle System in THREEJS/GLSL

Tags: three.js, glsl, particle-system, particles

I made a particle system with buffergeometry in threejs.  I want the particles to receive light.  <s>Is this difficult (impossible?) because the geometry doesn't actually have faces to light?</s>

I'm working with this mostly in a shader I created.  I just created the geometry in threejs.

Are particles not in world space?  Are they in camera space only?

What is a simple GLSL fragment shader equation for lighting particles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what kind of material you are using for the particles. If you are using shaderMaterial and write your own fragmentshader, then you have to implement lighting yourself in the shader code. For example, to lighten particles that are close to the light source, simply lighten their color by the distance between each particle and the light position:

```
vec3 lightPosition = vec3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
float lightStrength = 0.1;

float distanceToLightSource = distance(particlePosition, lightPosition);

vec4 lighterColor = particleColor * distanceToLightSource * lightStrength;
```

Comment: Wow, you simplified things so well.  I appreciate your response!  I thought of something of like that, but I'm not experienced enough with GLSL to just formulate the code for it.I do completely understand your answer though because I already added a light position in my shader and was toying with it.

Comment: That is great! You may also realize that the particle position is not natively available in the fragment shader, so it has to be passed from the vertex shader as a varying variable

Comment: Thanks, I was already passing the particle positions.  I really was close.  I just didn't have the equation for it.